# How to display nested data in MVC5 view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of companies that have a list of projects. I want to display all companies and all projects like so:

```
Company1
    Project1
    Project2
Company2
    Project3
    Project4
```

How can I accomplish this easily with asp.net MVC5?

EDIT:
I needed a concrete view example so that I could understand how to create the controller and model. Here's my controller and model.

```
Public Class CompanyModel
    Private _title As String
    Private _projects As New List(Of Project)

    Public Property title As String
        Get
            Return _title
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property projects As List(Of Project)
        Get
            Return _projects
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Project))
            _projects = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And controller function:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim Companies As New List(Of CompanyModel)

    Using db As New ProjectDBDataContext(ConnectionStrings("redacted").ConnectionString)
        Dim companyList = (From c In db.Companies Select c)
        For Each c In companyList
            Dim projects = (From p In db.Projects Where p.companyID = c.id Select p).ToList
            Companies.Add(New CompanyModel With {.title = c.title, .projects = projects})
        Next
    End Using
    Return View(Companies)
End Function
```

Then I just used Chris's example code for the view.

Comment: really poor question

Comment: This is far too broad. What are your models. Does typeof `Company` contain a collection of `Project`?

Comment: Gives us the codezzzzz!!!

Comment: I don't have any code. I have a Company table and a Project table in the database.

Comment: @quomationwebdev See my edit. I added a simple view and partial view to look at.

Comment: I needed a concrete view example so that I could understand how to create the controller and model. Edited question but Chris already provided an answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a nested For Each using Razor in the view to accomplish this.

Edit: Possible solution for you:

View:

```
@foreach (var company in Model) {
    @company.Name
    @Html.Partial("_Projects", company.Projects)
}
```

_Projects partial view:

```
@foreach (var project in Model) {
    @project.Name
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? In the nested loop, I need to get the projects for that company.

Comment: Do you have any experience with .NET MVC? Because if not there is absolutely no way to simply explain this to you. You need to learn the basics of it before anyone can give you examples to work with. Your concept involves creating models, accessing a database possibly, creating views and back end logic to map your models. Basically everything that makes MVC work.